# display the word present instead of a date in php array

Tags: php

Good day,

I am fairly new with PHP and I cannot figure out how to get it working. I had googled for solution but not found what I want.

I want to have a present checkbox added to my form. which i was able to do. i can either save it as a date or the word present but the problem is when i want to display the date on this format date('F j, Y', strtotime ) the value PRESENT which is save in my DB is showing July 1 1970 ( which i believe is the default for 0000-00-00 ).

NOTE: i use varchar to get both date and the value present save in the DB using the same column

my question now is there a way to display the word PRESENT and display the date('F j, Y', strtotime ) at the same time on my table?

just like the date option in jobstreet where you can display both date and the word present?

any help is much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: `if ($value === 'PRESENT') echo date('F j, Y');`

Comment: strtotime if a function it can be in used as date('F j, Y', strtotime('your time') );

Comment: may i know the reason for vote down so i can at least improve my question

Comment: don't know who do this?

Comment: @ErphilCatama For clarity, people generally like to see your existing code, what it outputs, and what you'd like it to output instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
if ($value === 'PRESENT') 
    echo date('F j, Y');
else 
    echo date('F j, Y', strtotime('your time') );
```

**EDIT:**

Then do it simply

```
 if ($value === 'PRESENT') 
        echo $value;
    else 
        echo date('F j, Y', strtotime('your time') );
```

Comment: thanks for replying i have updated my question as it may have confuse most of the readers.

what i wanted is display a list from my table that has dates and string (on my case just the word PRESENT) i am using this date('F j, Y', strtotime('your time') ); initially but i removed because php display present as a month/day/year what i only wanted was to have the word present together with the dates

Comment: then just replace `echo date('F j, Y');` by `echo $value;` in this answer and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your comments guys

i was able to figure out using all your answers and suggestion.

```
 if ($row ['LDATE'] == 'PRESENT') 
   echo 'PRESENT'; 
 else { 
   echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($row ['LDATE'])); }
```

here is the code i use.